# Scifi book where all human knowledge is stored in some kind of encrypted device - passwords are lost

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for a book I've never read that was mentioned in passing in an IT article about encryption.  It is a sci-fi post human (?) piece of fiction where all human knowledge of everything has been stored in some kind of electronic device.  However, no one can retrieve the valuable knowledge inside as the password(s) have been lost.

I have no idea how it ends or starts.  I've tried googling the plot line and ended up at this site.

Comment: Vaguely reminiscent of Hal Draper's ["MS Fnd in a Lbry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Fnd_in_a_Lbry). Think that could be it? Full text [here](http://home.comcast.net/~bcleere/texts/draper.html).

Comment: If that is the one you're looking for, they your question is a possible duplicate of [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70659/story-about-a-dystopian-future-involving-data-planets) and [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55962/story-about-a-library-built-in-the-ocean).

Comment: Thank you very much but don't think that was it.

Comment: Do you have a link to the IT article?

Comment: No, no link sorry .. I read it last year.  Cheers.

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but there is a related episode in Douglas Adams' *Mostly Harmless*.

Comment: Almost sounds like a variation of "The Library of Babel" by Jorge Luis Borges.

Answer (score 3):

While it isn't a password that is lost, the classic SF story "Twilight" by John Campbell has some of those elements.

A time travel visits the far future, and finds that men live in a world run by perfect machines, but they can't understand them because the language they use has changed over vast time.

> "What is its end? I have seen it -- almost. I saw them -- the little
>   men -- bewildered -- lost. And the machines. Must it be -- can't
>   anything sway it?
>
> "Listen -- I heard this song."
>
> He sang the song. Then he didn't have to tell me about the people. I
>   knew them. I could hear their voices, in the queer, crackling,
>   un-English words. I could read their bewildered longings. It was in a
>   minor key, I think. It called, it called and asked, and hunted
>   hopelessly. And over it all the steady rumble and whine of the
>   unknown, forgotten machines.
>
> The machines that couldn't stop, because they had been started, and
>   the little men had forgotten how to stop them, or even what they were
>   for, looking at them and listening -- and wondering. They couldn't
>   read or write any more, and the language had changed, you see, so that
>   the phonic records of their ancestors meant nothing to them.