# 1950s short story where the universe is running out of space to store data

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, computers

The universe is running out of room to store data. They have resorted to using "nudged electrons", IIRC. But the key to the storage of all human knowledge has been lost. Card catalog imagery/metaphor.

Comment: Hi Yellow. Could you please check-out our [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and fill us in with as many details as you can remember.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70659/story-about-a-dystopian-future-involving-data-planets or https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55962/story-about-a-library-built-in-the-ocean (neither of which has an accepted answer, so please do accept this answer if it is correct)

Comment: There was a reference in a Vonnegut story about running out of data storage space.  They decided to dump a bunch of stuff and their history books now read: "Following the death of Christ there was a period of adjustment that lasted about two thousand years".

Comment: I recall an Asimov (I think) story similar to this, but can't recall the name.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[*MS Fnd in a Lbry*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93729) by Hal Draper? It was published in 1961 so near about the time-frame you recall.

There are no "nudged atoms", but there is mention of "nudged quanta":

> Out of his work, ably supported by Drnt and Lccn, came the **nudged quanta**

> In no time at all, a quantic pizzicator was devised to compress the **nudged quanta** into overlapping spaces, most of these being arranged in the wide-open areas lying between the outer electrons and the nucleus of the atom, leaving the latter free for tables of contents, illustrations, graphs, etc.

Plot summary courtesy of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Fnd_in_a_Lbry):

> The story is in the form of a report written by Yrlh Vvg, an anthropologist from an alien civilization who investigates the remains of human civilization approximately 175,000 yukals into the future. It turns out that humankind's fall was **brought about by information overload and the inability to catalog and retrieve that information properly**.
>
> The title of the short story comes from the fact that all redundancy - and vowels - had been removed from our language in order for the information volume to shrink. Finally **the sum of all human knowledge was compressed by means of subatomic processes and stored away in a drawer-sized box**. However the access to that information required complicated indices, bibliographies etc., which soon outgrew the size of all knowledge.
>
> The use of indices **grew exponentially**, comprising a pseudo-city, pseudo-planet and eventually a pseudo-galaxy devoted to information storage. At this point, a case of circular reference was encountered, and **the civilization needed to refer to the first drawer-sized box to find the error. However, this drawer had been lost** in the pseudo-galaxy, and soon the civilization fell apart while trying to locate the first drawer.

Comment: Story text viewable at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v021n06_1961-12_PDF/page/n76/mode/1up).

Comment: As well as writing "The ABC of Marxism", Hal Draper was a microfilm acquisitions librarian at the University of California, which may have inspired this short story.

Comment: This answer has come up at least twice before, but neither was accepted. With all of the cases of people losing millions of dollars in bitcoin because they forgot a passphrase to a hard drive, this also seems incredibly plausible.

Comment: This is definitely the story I recall.