# Short story read 60+ years ago where mankind forgets how to do anything without a giant computer, possibly in a collection edited by Arthur C. Clarke

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The plot is simple. Mankind undertakes to store all of human knowledge in a giant computer. The computer grows so large that it has to be located on the moon. It can be accessed by a gigantic "index" computer located on earth.
Mankind relies more and more on this repository of knowledge and over time mankind forgets how to do anything without the computer. Teams of computer operators access instructions for all human activity.
The story ends with the computer's lead operator reporting that the computer access code is lost, and the code is so complicated that it may take years or decades to regain access!

I have some recollection that this story might have been included in an Arthur C. Clarke collection  entitled *"The Nine Billion Names of God"*, which is one of the stories included in the collection.

Comment: [The contents of the anthology The Nine Billion Names of God is available here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?44719). None of thestories look like the one you describe.

Comment: The anthologies that include the short story _The Nine Billion Names of God_ [are listed here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41108). But there are dozens of them!

Comment: It is definitely not in the collection *The Nine Billion Names of God.*  I own a copy of that book and there's nothing even remotely like your description in it

Comment: This reminds me strongly of "[MS Fnd in a Lbry](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93729)" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Fnd_in_a_Lbry), [original](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v021n06_1961-12_PDF/page/n76/mode/1up)) but that is much more retrospective, and it's not the access that's been lost it's the actual library.  (Though it does fit the timeframe; it was anthologized in [*17 X Infinity*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?36083), ed. Conklin, 1963.)

Comment: @DavidW It was lost data, but it was an index missing, which was needed to decode the rest.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I thought they had lots and lots of indexes but could not find the actual records, called Rx. As DavidW said.

Comment: Maybe I miread. "At this point, he called in the district Bibliothecal Technician who pointed out that the misnudged sequence could be restored only by reference to the original Rx."

Comment: "Somewhere in the galaxy-size flood of Ix drawers was the one and only drawer of Rx .... A desperate physical search was started, but it did not get very far, breaking down when it was found that no communication was possible in the first place without reference to the knowledge stored in the Rx."

Comment: @FuzzyBoots You could be right, it's a bit opaque with all the jargon.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots But ultimately it's the fact that the original records (Rx) are lost that causes (and exacerbates) the problem.

Comment: Ah, and indeed, the Rx is meant to refer to the central repository of information. I yield that I was wrong, but I'll still post it as an answer, because it's pretty dang close. :-D

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: There was a similar one I remember, about a planet-size computer that stopped to work due to a failing component, and they had to find an old man that remembered ohm's law... Can't find it at the moment.

Comment: From the title, I thought this was going to be the Asimov short story where Earth is in a state of permanent warfare with another world (Deneb?) until a technician discovers that humans can do math without a computer, which enables development of the "manned missile". Humans being much cheaper and more expendable than guidance computers, this is a massive leap forward in the war...

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of similarities to the 1961 short story Hal Draper's ["MS Fnd in a Lbry"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93729) by Hal Draper, published in the [*Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction*, December 1961](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v021n06_1961-12_PDF/page/n76/mode/1up). One detail that notably fits your question is that it was anthologized in [*17 X Infinity*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?76) (edited by Groff Conklin) in 1963, which places it just over 60 years ago.

In the story the entire knowledge of humanity is on a small drawer, while the various indexes and bibliographical data have expanded to fill literal galaxies.  Then one day a discrepancy is discovered between two indexes (Ix), that can only be resolved by looking up the original records (Rx).  Unfortunately, the location of the Rx can't be found, because it's in one of  the corrupted Ix.

The story has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Fnd_in_a_Lbry), or you can read the [original story](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v021n06_1961-12_PDF/page/n76/mode/1up).

Comment: I don't remember the details very well after all this time, but "MS And in a Lbry" sounds basically the story I remember reading long ago. I don't know why I thought it was somehow related to Nine Billion Names of God, but I may have just read them both during the early 1960s. Thanks to those who answered.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, this has a strong resemblance to "[MS Fnd in a Lbry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Fnd_in_a_Lbry)" by Hal Draper (readable [here](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v021n06_1961-12_PDF/page/n76/mode/1up)).

> The story is in the form of a report written by Yrlh Vvg, an anthropologist from an alien civilization who investigates the remains of human civilization approximately 175,000 yukals into the future. It turns out that humankind's fall was brought about by information overload and the inability to catalog and retrieve that information properly.
>
> The title of the short story comes from the fact that all redundancy - and vowels - had been removed from our language in order for the information volume to shrink. Finally the sum of all human knowledge was compressed by means of subatomic processes and stored away in a drawer-sized box. However the access to that information required complicated indices, bibliographies etc., which soon outgrew the size of all knowledge.
>
> The use of indices grew exponentially, comprising a pseudo-city, pseudo-planet and eventually a pseudo-galaxy devoted to information storage. At this point, a case of circular reference was encountered, and the civilization needed to refer to the first drawer-sized box to find the error. However, this drawer had been lost in the pseudo-galaxy, and soon the civilization fell apart while trying to locate the first drawer.

Unlike in your question, they still have a corrupted index (which is stored across an entirely galaxy), but they have lost the actual information drawer (which is the size of a drawer) that it refers to. But indeed, the story is a writeup in retrospect of the collapse of civilization due to the increasing corruption of the index.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255715/1950s-short-story-where-the-universe-is-running-out-of-space-to-store-data